On Weil's theorem that a rational group action becomes regular action after some birational modification
People attribute the following theorem to Weil:

Any variety $X$ equipped with a birational action of a connected algebraic group $G$ is equivariantly birationally isomorphic to a variety $Y$ equipped with a regular action of $G$.

For example, see Remark 2.3.7 in the book "Michel Brion, Preena Samuel, and V. Uma. Lectures on the structure of algebraic groups and geometric applications".
Is there a precise reference for this result - ideally written in the modern language of algebraic geometry?
In my case, the variety $X$ is normal and quasi-projective. Can $Y$ still be normal and quasi-projective?

Theorem 2.5 in S. Cantat. Morphisms between Cremona groups, and characterization of rational varieties. Compos. Math., 150(7):1107  should be useful.

Thank you! In Cantat's paper, he needs $G$ to have a bounded degree to do the regularization. Since my $G$ is connected, the degree of each element of $G$ should be bounded, right?

I just remembered another useful reference: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1799

Bounded degree is indeed automatic, because your G is an algebraic group. Also, have a look at [25] and [35] cited in Cantat's paper.

That is explained completely in “N’eron models” by Bosch, Luetkebohmert, and Raynard.

I am certain that they also list the citation to Weil’s original article (although I don’t recall it at this moment).

Besides the nice references mentioned by Ariyan JavanPeykar and Jason Starr, I feel that the paper "Regularization of Rational Group Actions" by Hanspeter Kraft is just what I need (see Section 1.7 and 1.8).
The rough idea is the following: first, by Weil's theorem, there exists a $G$-variety $X'$ which is $G$-equivariantly birational to $X$. Replacing $X'$ by its normalization which is still a $G$-variety. Then by the result of Sumihiro/Brion, there exists an $G$-invariant open set $U \subset X'$ which is quasi-projective. By another result of Sumihiro/Brion, $U$ admits a $G$-equivariant embedding into a projective $G$-variety $Y'$. Finally, take a $G$-equivariant resolution $Y \to Y'$, we get the desired projective and normal variety.
